# React: How to calculate a value and pass to parent so that siblings can use it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Imagine I have some logic that looks like this:

```
items = [1, 1, 2, 3, 1];
count = 0;
items.map((x) => {count += x; return count;})  // expected: [1, 2, 4, 7, 8]
```

Now I want to implement this in React, where a `Parent` component is responsible for rendering the whole array, and a `Child` component is responsible for rendering one item.

Admittedly, I'm new to React and unfamiliar with the inner workings, but my natural instinct is to somehow create a variable that can be passed back and forth between `Parent` and `Child`, where the `Child` is responsible for doing the `count += x` bit. Yet I just can't find a way to get it to work.

So far I have:

- Looked up various StackOverflow questions on "how to pass a value back to parent" but all of them seem to be about events (such as `onClick`). I'm not updating a value based on events, I just want to update the value in a loop.
- Tried to mess with states but honestly I have no idea what's going on and sometimes after changing one line of code my browser hangs and I have to kill it with task manager.
- Considered <s>giving up</s> just moving the calculation to `Parent` and make `Child` only responsible for rendering, however this feels ugly because 1) the logic of "handling one item" is not encapsulated in one place and <s>2) it means that I will need to iterate through the loop twice</s>.

The closest I have to working is this:

```
function Child({ item, addCount }) {
  const newCount = addCount(item);
  return <div>{newCount}</div>;
}

function Parent({ items }) {
  let count = 0;
  const addCount = (x) => {
    count += x;
    return count;
  };
  return items.map((item) => <Child item={item} addCount={addCount} />);
}

function App() {
  const items = [1, 1, 2, 3, 1];
  return (
    <Parent items={items} />
  );
}
```

However the result I get is `[2, 4, 8, 14, 16]`, which means each `Child` is called twice. Again I am new to React and I don't know what's going on behind the scenes. I don't even know if using a `let` variable this way would cause problems or not.

Any ideas or suggestions? What's the "correct" way to implement something like this?

EDIT:

I just realized that I don't need to iterate through the list twice. I could just calculate it inside `map`.

Thanks to comments pointing me in the direction, I have something working that looks like this:

```
function Child({ count }) {
  return <div>{count}</div>;
}

function Parent({ items }) {
  let count = 0;
  return items.map((item) => {
    count += item;
    return <Child count={count} />;
  });
}

function App() {
  const items = [1, 1, 2, 3, 1];
  return (
    <Parent items={items} />
  );
}
```

Admittedly my actual logic is a lot more complicated than this, and I'd rather `count += item;` and `<div>{count}</div>` stay in one place, but this should work for now.

Comment: There is an React.StrictMode in index.js?

Comment: Doing the calculation in the parent is absolutely the right thing. "Summing all the items in the list" is not what "handling one item" is about.

Comment: Have you read https://react.dev/learn/thinking-in-react? Also relevant: https://react.dev/learn/keeping-components-pure

Comment: @HumanoidMk.12 yes, why?

Comment: It renders twice for check bug. And React.StrictMode finds the bug in your code. the count variable causes bug.

Comment: @Bergi thanks for the links. I'll read them once my brain is more active. Also thanks for pointing out the direction - I really just needed someone more experienced to take a look at this.

Comment: always use useState to handle state.

Comment: @TomFan except this counting is not really state